# Android NDK: Aborting. Stops, after Android Studio update

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, android-ndk

I am working on an Android Project that uses OpenCV to send some images to a web server for further processing.

The idea is that everything was configured and running well, until I let `Android Studio` do an update, 1 or 2 days ago. Now I get this error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
```

Has anyone found a fix for this ?

I know that this question has been asked, but I can't find a solution in those answers. I haven't changed one line of code since the update and this is very annoying !

Thank you !

Comment: It would be good if you can post the error message before and after the one you posted here

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I solved it by creating a new project and moving the code from the old one and now it works. I just got tired of guessing whats wrong with the old project, I would recommend this "solution".